# mySQL calculate product of rows

Tags: mysql, math

I am searching for a function to get product of field across multiple rows - just like min() / max().

Scenario:

- Table 'pages' with multiple URL records
- Table 'tags' with multiple tags for each page record. Each tag has a int field for boosting.

Now I want to select several page records with their corresponding boost value - which is calculated via tag1-boost * tag2-boost * tagN-boost

Comment: How about some example data and expected output. And the query you are working on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a solution.

It's a combination of several MySQL functions.

EXP(SUM(LOG(field)))

Explanation can be found here:
http://knowledge.guenther-its.de/2017/07/12/mysql-aggregat-funktion-product/

Comment: Note that this will not work when you have field = 0